# jQuery click on span and travel

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, html

```
<span class="link">move your body</span>
```

**How to make this span a link, without adding any inline javascript and extra attributes?**

Also without transformation to `<a>`.

Like this:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
    // go to the http://site.com
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean this:

```
$("span.link").click(function(){
   $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
   window.location = 'www.example.com';
})
```

Comment: doesn't this only change the cursor after a click?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".link").click(function(){
    window.location = "http://example.com";
})
```

Also it would be a nice touch to add

```
.link { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: thanks and +1 to you too doing pretty much the similar thing :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".link").click(function(){
    window.location = "http://yoururl.com"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".link").click(function(){
    $(location).attr('href', $(this).text());
})
```

Comment: That would not work, $(this).text() would return move your body, which is not a link.